# Why artifactory jars are not downloading?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am totally new to maven.

I have written new pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<name>TestProject</name>

<groupId>com.test.te</groupId>
<artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
<version>1.1.6</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release-build</id>

        <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <finalName>testwar</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>

                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin> 
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I compiling this like this

```
mvn clean compile
```

Here is the response

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestProject
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting /home/workspace/TestProject/target
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/workspace/TestProject/src/main/resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 288 source files to /home/workspace/TestProject/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
/home/workspace/TestProject/src/main/java/com/test/te/Response.java:[9,28] error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
```

Comment: Never use dependencies in profiles.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have declared your dependencies inside a profile, you need to activate the profile. Try this:

`mvn -P release-build clean compile`

and it should work.

Also, here is a version of your POM that is less verbose and achieves the same thing, provided that you don't need the profile:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>TestProject</name>
  <groupId>com.test.te</groupId>
  <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.6</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
      <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
      <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>testwar</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is there any way to declare dependencies outside profile, in pom.xml itself?

Comment: Absolutely, that is the way you normally do it. Just move the `<dependencies>` section outside the `<profiles>` section, which you can remove. Remove the `<repositories>` section as well, it is completely redundant.

Comment: Added a less verbose version of your POM. Hopefully it'll make my explanation above clearer.